# deploy spring boot rest application on wildfly10

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a spring boot rest api which is developed on Java 1.8 and deployed on Wildfly 15. when I try to deploy it on wildfly 10 errors are reported and deployment fails.

```
>2019-04-05 21:47:29,228 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class at /G:/job/web/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/api.war/WEB-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.9.10.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 86
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:1409)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1443)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRo 
    ot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(Ann 
    otationIndexProcessor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceCon 
    trollerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerIm 
    pl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:114 
    9)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:62 
   4)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

>2019-04-05 21:47:30,196 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class module-info.class at /G:/job/web/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/api.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 32
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:1409)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1443)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

>2019-04-05 21:47:31,041 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.api.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.api.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.api.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1092)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1448)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1476)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
    ... 5 more

>2019-04-05 21:47:31,045 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.api.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.api.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.api.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported:main"}}
2019-04-05 21:47:31,059 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "api.war" (runtime-name : "api.war")
2019-04-05 21:47:31,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.module.service."deployment.api.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.api.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.api.war:main
```

Here are the content of the pom.xml all are for spring boot version 2.1.3.
I tried to downgrade to Byte Buddy (without Dependencies) » 1.5.13  and jaxb to 2.2.21 the warnings are gone but the errors are still exist.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>jdk.unsupported</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Are there any configuration changes to be done prior to deploying a spring boot application on wildfly 10?
Are there are any specific code changes to be done to deploy on wildfly 10?

Comment: It seems like spring boot 2 applications cannot be deployed on wildfly 10. I convert my project in to spring boot   1.5 and it deployed correctly